# Layout switcher (not just the css)

Tags: jquery, layout

I've been looking high and low, but I can't find a layout switcher that doesn't just let me switch css but also the html code and also saves the users chosen setting in a cookie.

I want to be able to have several site layouts and functions and let the user choose which he/she prefers. The content i.e. the text will be the same no matter what layout a user sets.

Does anyone know a jquery based code that allows this? I prefer jquery, but php would be acceptable too.

Comment: Why would you need to switch the html? The whole point in css is [you don't have to change the HTML](http://www.csszengarden.com/)

Comment: I'm not just looking to change the way the site looks, but also the functionality. I'm building several layouts with several different code tags. For example; one site uses a menu which needs a bit of code, that I do not use in layout 2, so if the user chooses to use the second layout, the menu code isn't needed. Look at it like this, I'm making three different sites with the same content.

Comment: Can't you store the content in an XML file, then parse out the required data into the layout? XSLT is quite good for that.

Comment: I totally agree with Eric, that's the definite way to go.

Comment: @Eric - I'm guessing a rudimentary example would be a good answer to the question. :)

Comment: Eric, can you put the comment in an answer and elaborate a bit on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your content as xml, in a format of your choosing. Something like the following

### Page.xml

Must be parsed as PHP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Layout-<?php echo $_COOKIE['layout'] ?>.xslt"?>
<page>
    <title> ... </title>
    <main-content> ... </main-content>
    <articles>
        <article>
            <title> ... </title>
            <content> ... </content>
        </article>
        <article> ... </article>
        <article> ... </article>
        <article> ... </article>
    </articles>
</page>
```

### Layout-[name].xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/page">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
        <html>
            <head>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </head>
            <body>
                ...
                <!-- copy node as HTML -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="main-content/node()" />
                ...
                <xsl:apply-templates match="articles/article" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article">
        <div>
            <h2><xsl:copy-of select="title" /></h2>

            <!-- copy node as HTML -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="content/node()" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can just deliver the XML page to the client, and their browser will do the transformation!